# Django block access to a detailview based on field

Tags: django, detailview

I have a detailView/template that has a `confidential` field (Boolean) and I want the detail page to be only accessible by staff users (or higher). I have currently made it work by adding the following to my template:

```
  {% if enzymes.confidential == True %}
    {% if user.is_staff %}
      # confidential data is listed here
    {% else %}
      <p>You do not have access to this page</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    # non confidential data is listed here
  {% endif %}
```

However, I want to know if I can't just apply a filter to my view? The view that I use is listed below (including a bit of leftover from what I tried).

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'gts/detail.html'
    model = Enzymes

    # The active get_context_data
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        enzyme = context['object']
        activities = Activitydiagram.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
        spectras = Spectraimage.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
        enzymeactivities = Enzymeactivity.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
        context['activities'] = activities
        context['spectras'] = spectras
        context['enzymeactivities'] = enzymeactivities
        return context

    # This was my WIP attempt
    """def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            enzyme = context['object']
            activities = Activitydiagram.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
            spectras = Spectraimage.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
            enzymeactivities = Enzymeactivity.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
            context['activities'] = activities
            context['spectras'] = spectras
            context['enzymeactivities'] = enzymeactivities
        else:
            # TODO: Load only confidential=False enzymes here
            enzyme = context['object']
            activities = Activitydiagram.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
            spectras = Spectraimage.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
            enzymeactivities = Enzymeactivity.objects.filter(enzymes=enzyme)
            context['activities'] = activities
            context['spectras'] = spectras
            context['enzymeactivities'] = enzymeactivities
        return context"""
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to compare values to `True` or `False` in Django templates. You can simplify `{% if enzymes.confidential == True %}` to `{% if enzymes.confidential %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical approach is to override the `get_queryset` method, and filter the queryset if the user isn't a staff member. If a non-staff member tries to access a confidential item, they'll get a 404 page.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'gts/detail.html'
    model = Enzymes

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(DetailView, self).get_queryset()
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            queryset = queryset.filter(confidential=False) 
        return queryset
```

Comment: Nice, can all of the default functions of a class be overwritten this way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The key benefit of class based generic views is that you can customise them by subclassing and overriding methods/attributes. The difficult bit can be knowing how the methods fit together, so that you know what to override.

Comment: I meant method indeed, my bad.